# How to fix "ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061]" when Selenium try to reconnect to existing session browser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I read all the post about this topic:
How to use/attach an existing browser using Selenium?
How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with...
Maintain and re-use existing webdriver browser instance ...
How to make Selenium Chrome Driver to open on a new tab in a ...

The solution is clear but I am facing an unexpected issue. I get the error message:

> "ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061]"

Here is my code:

```
file_path = 'existing_session.txt'
# check if size of file is 0
if path.exists(file_path) and os.stat(file_path).st_size != 0:
      print('File is not empty')
      ## GET SESSION ID and URL COMMAND FROM FILE
      f = open('existing_session.txt', 'r')
      fl = f.readlines()
      session_id = fl[0]
      url_command = fl[1]
      print("session_id" + session_id)
      print("url_command" + url_command)
      f.close()
      driver = webdriver(command_executor=url_command, desired_capabilities={})
      driver.session_id = session_id
```

As you can see, I am getting the `session_id` and `url` from a text file. When my code is running the first session, it saved session `id` and `url` in a text file in order to reconnect to session later.

So I didn't find any solution for this issue. I add rules in my firewall for letting `geckodriver.exe` going in and out. But it didn't fix my problem.

I am thinking about firewall issue. But maybe it is something else? Has anyone already faced this issue and know how to fix it please?